# Svelte Icon - keeps showing me an error "has no default export"

Tags: svelte

My Svelte Icon keeps showing me an error "has no default export" but actually works when I do `npm run dev`.

Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Sounds like an incorrect TypeScript definition.